# Regex para voltar a linha

Tags: regex, sublime-text

Sabendo que `\n` é uma quebra de linha, tem alguma que faça o inverso? Estou usando o `Sublime` como editor e meu texto está assim:

```
1,
2,
3,
```

Se transforme em:

```
1,2,3,
```

Existe alguma `regex` ou outro meio para isso?

Comment: `\n` não é uma expressão regular, é um caractere normal. Se quiser remover a quebra de linha basta remover esse caractere.

Comment: @Woss vou editar minha pergunta.

Comment: Bom, você leu todo o meu comentário anterior? Se ele é um caractere, basta removê-lo.

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta.

Comment: Não precisa de regex: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13578705

Comment: @Woss não entendi bem este remover o \n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Abrir "Find and Replace" (`CTRL+H`)
2. Habilitar "Regular Expression" (em vermelho)
3. Digitar \n+ (ou s+ ou \n\s+, dependendo do caso) no campo "Find", limpar o campo "Replace"
4. "Replace all"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Show..muito obrigado.